# Can any one tell what's going wrong with my Routine

Tags: asp.net, mysql

My requirement is if the user click on update data with out changing any field on the form i would like to show as No changes made and if any changes i would like to update the data

I have written a Routine for updating data as follows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspEmployeeFaxDetailsUpdate`(_EmpID int(11),
_FaxNumberTypeID varchar(45),
_FaxNumber decimal(10,0),
_EndDate datetime)

BEGIN

 declare p_ecount int;

  set p_ecount= (select count(1) from tblemployeefaxdetails  where
 FaxNumberTypeID=_FaxNumberTypeID and
 FaxNumber=_FaxNumber and
 EndDate='9999-12-31');

 if p_ecount=0 then

begin

 update tblemployeefaxdetails

  set

    EndDate=_EndDate WHERE EmpID=_EmpID and EndDate="9999-12-31";

    insert into tblemployeefaxdetails(EmpID,FaxNumberTypeID,FaxNumber,StartDate,EndDate) values
    (_EmpID,_FaxNumberTypeID,_FaxNumber,curdate(),'9999-12-31');

    end;
    end if;
```

END

I am getting some time my required message but some time it is showing the update message

This is my code on update

```
   oEmployeePersonalData.EmpID = EmpID;
        oEmployeePersonalData.FaxNumberTypeID = ddlFaxTypeID.SelectedItem.Text;
        oEmployeePersonalData.FaxNumber = Convert.ToInt64(txtFaxNumber.Text);
        oEmployeePersonalData.EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        if (oEmployeePersonalData.FaxDetailUpdate())
        {
            oMsg.Message = "Updated Sucessfully";
            Label m_locallblMessage;
            oMsg.AlertMessageBox(out m_locallblMessage);
            Page.Controls.Add(m_locallblMessage);
                       }
        else
        {
            oMsg.Message = "Not Sucessfully";
            Label m_locallblMessage;
            oMsg.AlertMessageBox(out m_locallblMessage);
            Page.Controls.Add(m_locallblMessage);
        }
```

Updated code

```
   public bool FaxDetailUpdate()
    {
        m_bFlag = false;
        try
        {

            m_oCmd = new MySqlCommand(StoredProcNames.tblEmployeeFaxdetails_uspEmployeeFaxdetailsUpdate, m_oConn);
            m_oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_EmpID", EmpID);
            m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_FaxNumberTypeID", FaxNumberTypeID);
            m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_FaxNumber", FaxNumber);
            m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_EndDate", EndDate);
            if (m_oConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                m_oConn.Open();
            }
            if ((m_oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) > 0)
            {
                this.m_bFlag = true;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException oSqlEx)
        {
            m_sbErrMsg.Length = 0;
            m_sbErrMsg = Utilities.SqlErrorMessage(oSqlEx);
            //DB write the Error Log
            m_oErrlog.Add(m_sbErrMsg.ToString(), DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception oEx)
        {
            m_sbErrMsg = Utilities.ErrorMessage(oEx);
            //DB write the Error Log
            m_oErrlog.Add(m_sbErrMsg.ToString(), DateTime.Now);
        }
        finally
        {
            m_oConn.Close();
        }
        return this.m_bFlag;
    }
```

I am not getting any error but i would like to be done as per i said

Can any one tell what changes i have to made in this

Comment: Can you give more details of the error? Can you at least show the code for `FaxDetailUpdate()`?

Comment: @Kelloti :- I am not getting any error but i would like to be done as per my requirement as i said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand the routine, what the magic date `9999-12-31` represents, and why a new record is inserted every time, instead of updating the old one.

What you can do, is have the routine return a indicator if the row was changed or not, returning the value of `p_ecount` through a `OUT` parameter.

For more information on how to use `OUT` parameters using the .net MySql client see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-stored.html

Comment: Actually i am doing a payroll information so i should not edit the old record the old record should be the same and the edits should be updated and to be saved when coming to date it is the end date

Comment: I think the magic date is supposed to be DateTime.Max. @Dorababu, I have a feeling `EndDate` should be a nullable column with `null` meaning that it never ends. If you're feeling brave I suggest you refactor the database to be this way.